# Prepared Statement in Java fails when SQL trigger is enabled

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, triggers

I have built an Eclipse Java plugin which has a function which copies selected XML files to a server, then runs a SQL prepared statement which populates a table called XMLInsertion, which in turn activates a SQL trigger which does a bulk read from the XML files and updates XMLInsertion and another table WeedingReports. This worked beautifully until I opened it a few days back, so something has occurred in the meantime.

If the SQL trigger is disabled the prepared statement works. If I enable the trigger neither work, with the error "Error! Cannot bulk load. The file "blah" does not exist." The SQL trigger works if I enter data through SQL Server. This suggests a permissions issue, but how can this be if neither the trigger or the insert is working via the plugin, as the error suggests the trigger can't find the file, but the trigger needs to read from XMLInsertion which isn't being populated to activate the trigger - confusing?

Two questions

- If neither the prepared statement or trigger run how does the error occur? The error relates to BULK LOAD, which is within the trigger, but the trigger relies on the data entered from the prepared statement, which never executes.
- Why is the prepared statement not running at all ONLY when the trigger is enabled?

  ```
  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://gissrv;databaseName=bushland_dev;user=blah;password=blah;");     

  PreparedStatement insertXMLTable = connection.prepareStatement("UPDATE Bushland_Dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION SET FILEPATH = ?, FILENAME = ?, TRIGGERFIELD = ? WHERE FILENAME = ?");

  insertXMLTable.setString(1,destination.toString());
  insertXMLTable.setString(2,destination.getFileName().toString());
  insertXMLTable.setString(3,GMSCKey);
  insertXMLTable.setString(4,destination.toString());
  insertXMLTable.executeUpdate();
  ```

It worked fine until a few days ago so I imagine someone has changed permissions, as I haven't made any changes myself.

DDLS Below

XMLInsertion Trigger

```
USE [bushland_dev]
    GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[XML_Permission] ON [bushland_dev].[dbo].[XMLINSERTION] 
AFTER UPDATE, INSERT
AS

IF (SELECT COUNT(TRIGGERFIELD) FROM XMLINSERTION WHERE TRIGGERFIELD < 0) IS 
NOT NULL

BEGIN

CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
XMLData XML,
LoadedDateTime DATETIME
)

DECLARE @Filepath AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Filepath2 AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @Filepath = '\\GMSRVDEV\XML\'+(SELECT [FILENAME] FROM bushland_dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION WHERE TRIGGERFIELD > 0)+''

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(max)
SET @SQL = 'SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn, GETDATE() FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+@Filepath+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x' 

Insert into #Temp (XMLData,LoadedDateTime)

    exec(@SQL)

    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT

    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM #Temp

    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML      

    DECLARE @FormFields TABLE (ID int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, TabNum int, fieldName varchar(50), value nvarchar(max));

    WITH NumberMethods AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Method' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Method[1]','int') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Method FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHours AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Hours' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Hours[1]','float') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [Hours] FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberComments AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Comments' AS fieldname, ex.value('Comments[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Comments FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberFollowUpNotes AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'FollowUpNotes' AS fieldname, ex.value('FollowUpNotes[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS FollowUpNotes FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_1' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_1[1]','int') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_1 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_Rate_1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_Rate_1' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_Rate_1[1]','float') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_Rate_1 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_Qty_1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_Qty_1' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_Qty_1[1]','float') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_Qty_1 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_2' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_2[1]','int') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_2 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_Rate_2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_Rate_2' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_Rate_2[1]','float') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_Rate_2 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_Qty_2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_Qty_2' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_Qty_2[1]','float') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_Qty_2 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberHerbicide_IsSurfactant_2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2' AS fieldname, CAST(ex.value('Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2[1]','int') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberWeed_1 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Weed_1' AS fieldname, ex.value('Weed_1[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Weed_1 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberWeed_2 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Weed_2' AS fieldname, ex.value('Weed_2[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Weed_2 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberWeed_3 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Weed_3' AS fieldname, ex.value('Weed_3[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Weed_3 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberWeed_4 AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'Weed_4' AS fieldname, ex.value('Weed_4[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Weed_4 FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex)),
    NumberTaskID AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [ROW], 'ActivityID' AS fieldname, ex.value('ActivityID[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS ActivityID FROM @xml.nodes('/dataroot/MPSExport') AS A(ex))

    INSERT INTO @formfields (TabNum, fieldname, value)
    SELECT * FROM NumberMethods WHERE Method IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHours WHERE [Hours] IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberComments WHERE Comments IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberFollowUpNotes WHERE FollowUpNotes IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_1 WHERE Herbicide_1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_Rate_1 WHERE Herbicide_Rate_1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_Qty_1 WHERE Herbicide_Qty_1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_2 WHERE Herbicide_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_Rate_2 WHERE Herbicide_Rate_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_Qty_2 WHERE Herbicide_Qty_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberHerbicide_IsSurfactant_2 WHERE Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberWeed_1 WHERE Weed_1 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberWeed_2 WHERE Weed_2 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberWeed_3 WHERE Weed_3 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberWeed_4 WHERE Weed_4 IS NOT NULL
        UNION all
    SELECT * FROM NumberTaskID WHERE ActivityID IS NOT NULL OR ActivityID <> 0

    SELECT * FROM @FormFields

    UPDATE Bushland_dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION
    SET XMLINSERTION.[M1_METHOD] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName= 'Method' AND TabNum = 2),
    XMLINSERTION.[HOURS] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Hours' AND TabNum = 1),
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE1] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_1' AND TabNum = 2), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE2] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_2' AND TabNum = 2), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE1RATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_1' AND TabNum = 2),
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE1ADDRATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_2' AND TabNum = 2),      
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE1QTY] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Qty_1' AND TabNum = 2),       
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2' AND TabNum = 2), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_WEED1] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_1' AND TabNum = 2)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_WEED2] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_2' AND TabNum = 2)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_WEED3] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_3' AND TabNum = 2)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_WEED4] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_4' AND TabNum = 2)),
    XMLINSERTION.[M1_WEEDCOMMENTS] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Comments' AND TabNum = 2),
    XMLINSERTION.[Priority_Tasks] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'FollowUpNotes' AND TabNum = 2),
    XMLINSERTION.[ActivityID1] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'ActivityID' AND TabNum = 2),

    XMLINSERTION.[M2_METHOD] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName= 'Method' AND TabNum = 3),        
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE1] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_1' AND TabNum = 3), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE2] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_2' AND TabNum = 3),  
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE2RATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_1' AND TabNum = 3),
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE2ADDRATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_2' AND TabNum = 3),
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE2QTY] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Qty_2' AND TabNum = 3), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2' AND TabNum = 3), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_WEED1] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_1' AND TabNum = 3)),
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_WEED2] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_2' AND TabNum = 3)),
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_WEED3] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_3' AND TabNum = 3)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_WEED4] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_4' AND TabNum = 3)),
    XMLINSERTION.[M2_WEEDCOMMENTS] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Comments' AND TabNum = 3),
    XMLINSERTION.[ActivityID2] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'ActivityID' AND TabNum = 3),

    XMLINSERTION.[M3_METHOD] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName= 'Method' AND TabNum = 4),        
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE1] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_1' AND TabNum = 4), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE2] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_2' AND TabNum = 4), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE3RATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_1' AND TabNum = 4),
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE3ADDRATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_2' AND TabNum = 4),
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE3QTY] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Qty_3' AND TabNum = 4), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2' AND TabNum = 4), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_WEED1] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_1' AND TabNum = 4)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_WEED2] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_2' AND TabNum = 4)),  
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_WEED3] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_3' AND TabNum = 4)),  
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_WEED4] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_4' AND TabNum = 4)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M3_WEEDCOMMENTS] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Comments' AND TabNum = 4),
    XMLINSERTION.[ActivityID3] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'ActivityID' AND TabNum = 4),

    XMLINSERTION.[M4_METHOD] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName= 'Method' AND TabNum = 5),        
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE1] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_1' AND TabNum = 5), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE2] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_2' AND TabNum = 5), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE4RATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_1' AND TabNum = 5),
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE4ADDRATE] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Rate_2' AND TabNum = 5), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE4QTY] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_Qty_4' AND TabNum = 5), 

    XMLINSERTION.[M4_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Herbicide_IsSurfactant_2' AND TabNum = 5), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_WEED1] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_1' AND TabNum = 5)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_WEED2] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_2' AND TabNum = 5)),  
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_WEED3] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_3' AND TabNum = 5)),  
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_WEED4] = (SELECT ID FROM TARGET_WEEDS_LOOKUP WHERE NLinks_Ref IN (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Weed_4' AND TabNum = 5)), 
    XMLINSERTION.[M4_WEEDCOMMENTS] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'Comments' AND TabNum = 5),
    XMLINSERTION.[ActivityID4] = (SELECT VALUE FROM @FormFields WHERE fieldName = 'ActivityID' AND TabNum = 5)


    WHERE TRIGGERFIELD > 0

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc

    DROP TABLE #Temp

UPDATE b
    SET Hrs_Worked = x.HOURS,
    Method1 = x.M1_METHOD,
    Method1_Herbicide = x.M1_HERBICIDE1,
    Method1_Rate = ROUND(x.M1_HERBICIDE1RATE, 2),
    Method1_Add_Rate = ROUND(x.M1_HERBICIDE1ADDRATE, 2),
    Method1_Litres_Used = x.M1_HERBICIDE1QTY,
    Method1_Surface = x.M1_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT,
    Method1_Add_Herbicide = x.M1_HERBICIDE2,
    Method1_Weeds = x.M1_WEED1,
    Method1_Weeds2 = x.M1_WEED2,
    Method1_Weeds3 = x.M1_WEED3,
    Method1_Weeds4 = x.M1_WEED4,
    Method1_Details = x.M1_WEEDCOMMENTS,
    Priority_Tasks = x.PRIORITY_TASKS,
    NLinks_ActivityID1 = x.ActivityID1,
    Method2 = x.M2_METHOD,
    Method2_Herbicide = x.M2_HERBICIDE1,
    Method2_Add_Herbicide = x.M2_HERBICIDE2,
    Method2_Rate = ROUND(x.M2_HERBICIDE2RATE,2),
    Method2_Add_Rate = ROUND(x.M2_HERBICIDE2ADDRATE,2),
    Method2_Litres_Used = x.M2_HERBICIDE2QTY,
    Method2_Surface = x.M2_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT,
    Method2_Weeds = x.M2_WEED1,
    Method2_Weeds2 = x.M2_WEED2,
    Method2_Weeds3 = x.M2_WEED3,
    Method2_Weeds4 = x.M2_WEED4,
    Method2_Details = x.M2_WEEDCOMMENTS,
    NLinks_ActivityID2 = x.ActivityID2,
    Method3 = x.M3_METHOD,
    Method3_Herbicide = x.M3_HERBICIDE1,
    Method3_Add_Herbicide = x.M3_HERBICIDE2,
    Method3_Rate = ROUND(x.M3_HERBICIDE3RATE,2),
    Method3_Add_Rate = ROUND(x.M3_HERBICIDE3ADDRATE,2),
    Method3_Litres_Used = x.M3_HERBICIDE3QTY,
    Method3_Surface = x.M3_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT,
    Method3_Weeds = x.M3_WEED1,
    Method3_Weeds2 = x.M3_WEED2,
    Method3_Weeds3 = x.M3_WEED3,
    Method3_Weeds4 = x.M3_WEED4,
    Method3_Details = x.M3_WEEDCOMMENTS,
    NLinks_ActivityID3 = x.ActivityID3,
    Method4 = x.M4_METHOD,
    Method4_Herbicide = x.M4_HERBICIDE1,
    Method4_Add_Herbicide = x.M4_HERBICIDE2,
    Method4_Rate = ROUND(x.M4_HERBICIDE4RATE,2),
    Method4_Add_Rate = ROUND(x.M4_HERBICIDE4ADDRATE,2),
    Method4_Litres_Used = x.M4_HERBICIDE4QTY,
    Method4_Surface = x.M4_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT,
    Method4_Weeds = x.M4_WEED1,
    Method4_Weeds2 = x.M4_WEED2,
    Method4_Weeds3 = x.M4_WEED3,
    Method4_Weeds4 = x.M4_WEED4,
    Method4_Details = x.M4_WEEDCOMMENTS,
    NLinks_ActivityID4 = x.ActivityID4

FROM
Bushland_dev.dbo.Weeding_Reports b INNER JOIN Bushland_dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION 
x ON b.GMSC_Key = x.TRIGGERFIELD
WHERE b.GMSC_Key = x.TRIGGERFIELD

UPDATE Bushland_dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION
SET TRIGGERFIELD = 0,
Imported = 1
FROM
Bushland_dev.dbo.XMLINSERTION x INNER JOIN Bushland_dev.dbo.Weeding_Reports 
b
ON b.GMSC_Key = x.TRIGGERFIELD
WHERE x.TRIGGERFIELD = b.GMSC_Key       

END

GO
```

XML_Insertion Table

```
USE [bushland_dev]
    GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[XMLINSERTION](
[FILEPATH] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[FILENAME] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Hours] [float] NULL,
[TRIGGERFIELD] [int] NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE1] [int] NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE1RATE] [real] NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE1QTY] [float] NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] [int] NULL,
[M1_WEED1] [int] NULL,
[M1_WEED2] [int] NULL,
[M1_WEED3] [int] NULL,
[M1_WEED4] [int] NULL,
[M1_WEEDCOMMENTS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[PRIORITY_TASKS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE2] [int] NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE2RATE] [real] NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE2QTY] [float] NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] [int] NULL,
[M2_WEED1] [int] NULL,
[M2_WEED2] [int] NULL,
[M2_WEED3] [int] NULL,
[M2_WEED4] [int] NULL,
[M2_WEEDCOMMENTS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE3] [int] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE3RATE] [real] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE3QTY] [float] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] [int] NULL,
[M3_WEED1] [int] NULL,
[M3_WEED2] [int] NULL,
[M3_WEED3] [int] NULL,
[M3_WEED4] [int] NULL,
[M3_WEEDCOMMENTS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE4] [int] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE4RATE] [real] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE4QTY] [float] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE1SURFECTANT] [int] NULL,
[M4_WEED1] [int] NULL,
[M4_WEED2] [int] NULL,
[M4_WEED3] [int] NULL,
[M4_WEED4] [int] NULL,
[M4_WEEDCOMMENTS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
[Imported] [int] NULL,
[M1_METHOD] [varchar](10) NULL,
[M2_METHOD] [varchar](10) NULL,
[M3_METHOD] [varchar](10) NULL,
[M4_METHOD] [varchar](10) NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE2] [int] NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE1] [int] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE1] [int] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE2] [int] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE1] [int] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE2] [int] NULL,
[M1_HERBICIDE1ADDRATE] [real] NULL,
[M2_HERBICIDE2ADDRATE] [real] NULL,
[M3_HERBICIDE3ADDRATE] [real] NULL,
[M4_HERBICIDE4ADDRATE] [real] NULL,
[WR_GMSC_Key] [int] NULL,
[ActivityID1] [int] NULL,
[ActivityID2] [int] NULL,
[ActivityID3] [int] NULL,
[ActivityID4] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Weeding_Report Table

```
USE [bushland_dev]
    GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Weeding_Reports](
[GMSC_KEY] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Author] [varchar](80) NULL,
[Hrs_Worked] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Weeds] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Add_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Add_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Surface] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Method1_Surface_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Litres_Used] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Details] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Method2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Weeds] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Add_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Add_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Surface] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Method2_Surface_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Litres_Used] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Details] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Method3] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Weeds] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Add_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Add_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Surface] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Method3_Surface_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Litres_Used] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Details] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Method4] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Weeds] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Add_Herbicide] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Add_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Surface] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Method4_Surface_Rate] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Litres_Used] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Details] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Auditor] [varchar](80) NULL,
[Audit_Others_Present] [varchar](80) NULL,
[Methods_Applied] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Methods_Applied_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Timing_Appropriate] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Timing_Appropriate_com] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Herbicide_Appropriate] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Herbicide_Appropriate_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Accecptable_Kill] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Accecptable_Kill_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Off_Target_Kill] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Off_Target_Kill_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Thorough_Works] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Thorough_Works_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Cautions_Adhered] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Cautions_Adhered_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Instructions_Adhered] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Instructions_Adhered_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Works_Impact] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Works_Impact_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Weeding_Management_FK] [int] NULL,
[Geometry] [varbinary](max) NULL,
[Geometry_spa] [geometry] NULL,
[off_Target_Damage_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[non_Treated_Weeds_com] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Priority_Tasks] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Next_Visit] [varchar](500) NULL,
[Method1_Weeds2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Weeds3] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Weeds4] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Weeds2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Weeds3] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method2_Weeds4] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Weeds2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Weeds3] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method3_Weeds4] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Weeds2] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Weeds3] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Method4_Weeds4] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Audit_Date] [date] NULL,
[ACTION_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Works_On_Target_com] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[Works_On_Target] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[off_Target_Damage] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[non_Treated_Weeds] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Date] [date] NULL,
[Locked] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Rate] [float] NULL,
[Further_Comments] [nvarchar](1000) NULL,
[isDisposed] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Methods_Applied_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Timing_Appropriate_res] [varchar](1000) NULL,
[Herbicide_Appropriate_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Accecptable_Kill_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Off_Target_Kill_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Thorough_Works_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Cautions_Adhered_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Instructions_Adhered_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Works_Impact_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Works_On_Target_res] [varchar](750) NULL,
[Responder] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Responder_date] [date] NULL,
[Crew_Leader] [varchar](80) NULL,
[isArchived] [varchar](10) NULL,
[Financial_Year] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[Method1_Other] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Method2_Other] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Method3_Other] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Method4_Other] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
[Weeds_Targeted_Other1] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Weeds_Targeted_Other2] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Weeds_Targeted_Other3] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[Weeds_Targeted_Other4] [nvarchar](200) NULL,
[FILEPATH] [int] NULL,
[NLinks_ActivityID1] [int] NULL,
[NLinks_ActivityID2] [int] NULL,
[NLinks_ActivityID3] [int] NULL,
[NLinks_ActivityID4] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Comment: So to clarify, the SQL prepared statement is an insert into a table which should run regardless of the trigger or not. For some reason when the trigger is enabled neither run. I've tried setting the trigger to run on both FOR and AFTER UPDATE, INSERT. It doesn't make a difference. The insert just doesn't want to work with the trigger enabled.

Comment: Please include the DDL of the table and of the trigger.

Comment: See DDLS attached. Sorry if it is long.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into an extremely similar issue using the c++ sqlite bindings. If the trigger has ANY typo in the BEGIN ... END; section, it will actually still allow the trigger to be added but break the tables it is referencing. I had a typo in my trigger and it appeared to still add the trigger, but preparing a statement that would insert values into one of the tables referenced failed with a generic logic error. I would suggest reading your trigger very very carefully to make sure you have no typos in it.